# Need help identifying this robot from a cardboard cutout

Tags: robots, character-identification

My neighbor has this large cardboard cutout of a robot with a chicken burger, obviously part of some fast food ad campaign.

**I'm curious to know if the robot in question is from some specific work, or if it was created just for this campaign. Also, what company was the campaign for?**

[image]

Comment: I like the "R U R" logo on it's chest.

Comment: "Machines can't eat it. Machines shouldn't make it" - That's the slogan for a Robotics Union when they go on strike for better conditions.

Comment: ...and here I read the title as "How do I distinguish between a robot and a cardboard cutout?"

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I could see that. Now I need help identifying this alien from a stuffed animal. https://poppoppa.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/et-blending-in-in-the-closet.jpg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears this is just an ad for Carl's Jr. and the robot was created for the ad. [Ad](http://www.therobotreport.com/news/carls-jr-ad-say-if-machines-cant-eat-it-machines-shouldnt-make-it-but-robo)
[image]

[Robot was designed by the people who designed the terminator and Iron Man](http://www.foodbeast.com/news/carls-jr-hardees-employ-a-robot-in-new-ad-campaign/)

Comment: I would never eat at a restaurant that also served robots.

Comment: There's also an [extended version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pDNIkNLjRU)

Answer (score 2):

It's just for an [ad campaign](http://www.therobotreport.com/news/carls-jr-ad-say-if-machines-cant-eat-it-machines-shouldnt-make-it-but-robo), for the fast food outlets Carl's Jr. and Hardee's.